# .getAttribute() method on elements returned by querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value of data attributes from multiple div elements. The elements are captured into a variable using

> querySelectorAll()

I'm getting an error when I loop through the variable that contains the element and use the **getAttribute()** Method:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" data-speed="2" id="one"></div>
  <div class="box" data-speed="3" id="two"></div>
  <div class="box" data-speed="4" id="three"></div>
  <div class="box" data-speed="5" id="four"></div>
  <div class="box" data-speed="6" id="five"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
(function() {

var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 254) + 1);

boxes[i].style.background = "rgba(" + r + "," + i*30 + "," + i*45 + ", 1)";

}
})();

var divArray = [];
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

for (i = 0; i <= divs.length; i++) {

console.log(divs[i]);

var speed = parseInt(divs[i].getAttribute("data-speed"));

};
```

Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/L8xsvzL1/1/

When I

> console.log(divs[i])

it shows the element, I don't know why I'm unable to use the attribute method on it.

Any pointer would be really appreciated!

Comment: "I'm getting an error" — What error?

Comment: Sorry I updated my jsfiddle, it was pointing to the old one:

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are 0 index based

use

```
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for (i = 0; i <= divs.length; i++) {
```

due to this you are getting last divs[i] as undefined and thats why console display that error

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n3qhan4e/

Comment: Oh god, this is such an novice mistake on my part, thank you for your help.

Comment: @kshatriiya : NP :)  glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(elem => console.log(elem.getAttribute('data-speed')));
```